# Ir a otro controlador desde javascript

Tags: javascript, razor, mvc

Quiero redireccionar desde una vista a un controlador que esta un nivel más alto, para ello utilizo `@url.action` de este modo

```
miUrl = '@Url.Action("CambiarEstadoVisita", "~/Areas/Visitas/Visita")';
```

Pero el link que genera es este:

```
http://localhost:10174/Mantenimiento/~/Areas/Visitas/Visita/CambiarEstadoVisita
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para ir hacia atrás ?

Comment: Que quieres decir con "ir hacia atrás"?

Comment: yo tengo esta estructura Areas/Visitas/Controllers/VisitaController 
y estoy en
Areas/Mantenimiento/View/Usuario
de Usuario quiero llamar al controlador VisitaController

Comment: la primera opcion me genera esta ruta 
http://areas/Visitas/Controllers/VisitaController/CambiarEstadoVisita  y la segunda me genera una excepcion

Comment: lo que pasa que la primera me la pone asi del 
http:// areas/Visitas/Controllers/VisitaController/CambiarEstadoVisi‌​ta se come el localhost y el puerto

Comment: quita el `~` creo que con eso ya está.

Comment: quitando el ~ me hace bien la ruta pero no la encuentra da error, no tiene mucho sentido

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ya conseguí solucionarlo. En vez de usar `url.Action` que no me dejaba navegar hacia atrás con los `../`

```
miUrl = '@Url.Action("CambiarEstadoVisita", "../../Visitas/Visita")';
```

la `url` la cree como `string`

```
 miUrl = '../../Visitas/Visita/CambiarEstadoVisita';
```

y la pase por `ajax`

Comment: Te recomiendo que no abras una respuesta a tu pregunta, es preferible que Edites tu Pregunta y coloque la respuesta si es que no encontraste una respuesta correcta entre las postuladas... Ahora si encontraste una respuesta entre las colocadas, elige la mejor respuesta para que esta sea una referencia en próximas preguntas.

Comment: @AlfonsoCarrasco creo que tu comentario no aplica, porque es una respuesta a su propio problema y es valido

Comment: @JuankGlezz yo creo que si porque su solución está basada en respuestas y trabajo colaborativo con otros participantes. Si no hubiera ninguna respuesta entonces aplica responder tu mismo tu pregunta, cuando encuentres la solución...

Comment: @AlfonsoCarrasco la sección de preguntas es para colocar el texto de la pregunta. Para las respuesta (incluso respuestas a tus propias preguntas) se utiliza la sección de respuestas. Esta respuesta es completamente válida.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes mal la estructura del ayudante, debería ser:

```
@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName", new { id = "<id>" });
```

donde esta compuesta `(vista,controlador,parámetros(opcional))`, esta te genera una salida de la siguiente forma:

```
 /controllerName/actionName/<id>
```